# How to make Rebus play nice with a custom topic exchange in RabbitMQ?

Tags: rabbitmq, rebus

Rebus has flexible system that allows me to specify different endpoints for different message types, either in `web.config` or by implementing a custom `IDetermineMessageOwnership`.

As far as I can tell, message ownership is represented simply by a string. Using the MSMQ transport, this string points to a queue to which the message is delivered. With RabbitMQ, the string is used as a *topic* for the message, which is then delivered to a generic *exchange* named "Rebus". Rebus is a nice fellow, so he also sets up a *queue* in the RabbitMQ server, using  the same name, and makes a *binding* from topic to queue within the Rebus exchange.

My question is this: Is it possible to have Rebus **not** create queues and bindings, but still deliver the messages to an exchange with a relevant topic set for each message?

Declaring the queues and bindings manually will allow me to set up an awesome topic exchange, using bindings with wildcards and what not. Here is a nice illustration of a topic exchange with funky bindings, just to make my question look more sleek and sexy:

[image: Illustration of topic exchange in RabbitMQ]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds to me like you want to do something like this:

```
Configure.With(yourFavoriteContainer)
         .Transport(t => t.UseRabbitMq(...)
                          .ManageSubscriptions()) //< BAM!!1
         .(...)
```

which lets Rebus take advantage of the fact that Rebus' `RabbitMqMessageQueue` implements `IMulticastTransport`, which in turn turns handling of all things multicast over to Rabbit.

It's just important that all of your Rabbit-enabled Rebus endpoints agree on letting Rabbit `ManageSubscriptions`  - otherwise, weird stuff might happen ;)

It means that

- when you `bus.Subscribe<SomeEvent>`, you bind a topic with the type name to the subscriber's input queue - e.g. `"SomeEvent.SomeNamespace" -> myInputQueue`
- publishers publish events on a topic that is the type name - e.g. `"SomeEvent.SomeNamespace"`
- message ownership is disregarded when subscribing
- Rabbit will do the heavy lifting when doing multicast (which is what Rabbit users are mostly doing)

If you require even more flexibility, you can even take responsibility of deciding the topic to publish to for each .NET type, like so:

```
Configure.With(yourFavoriteContainer)
         .Transport(t => t.UseRabbitMq(...)
                          .ManageSubscriptions()
                          .AddEventNameResolver(type => DecideTopic(type))
         .(...)
```

You can add multiple event name resolvers if you want - they will be run in sequence until one of them returns something that is not `null`.

Does it make sense?

Comment: Your answer seems to assume a publish/subscribe style implementation. I am not sure if that is what I want. My messages are all of types which have a single endpoint for handling them, only I would like to define the route to this endpoint in terms of RabbitMQ, rather than in web.config or code.

Comment: Example: our website will send messages of five different types. They all go into via same exchange to a single queue on the local RabbitMQ installation, from where they are all shoveled to an exchange on a backend box where the topic/routing key is used to split them into three separate queues for three endpoints. If later we want to move one of the three endpoints to another box, the sysadmin can configure this via RabbitMQ's web interface without touching the website. Is this insane?

Comment: Don't call `bus.Subscribe<SomeEvent>` then - and then create and maintain the binding from topics named after the pretty full name of the .NET type - e.g. `SomeNamespace.SomeEvent`

Comment: I have added `ManageSubscriptions()` to my config and set up a binding from `Namespace.*` to a queue in the Rebus exchange on RabbitMQ. When I do `bus.Publish(msg)` nothing appears to happen now. The app console output says "Sending Namespace.Type to Namespace.Type", but all I see on the RabbitMQ admin pages are zeroes :(

Comment: Hmm, I can't think of a reason why that would not work...... This is just a guess, but do you happen to have more dots in the type name? E.g. is the actual implementation type's full name actually something like `Namespace.Subnamespace.Type`? Because then you should use # as the wildcard in the binding. The * only matches one .-delimited element, as in 'A.B' would match 'A.*', but 'A.B.C' would not...

Comment: I owe you a beer! My wildcard binding was indeed the culprit. Everything seems to be running smooth now. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: I'm here from the future, and `ManageSubscriptions` does not exist. Is there a way to do this with the latest version of Rebus?

Comment: Just found the answer: https://github.com/rebus-org/Rebus.RabbitMq/issues/2